# raise events in c++/cli dll and consume in c#

Tags: c#, c++-cli

In my c# app I have a progressbar. C# app is calling a c++/cli dll which processes a number of files. As each file is processed in the dll I would like to track it's progress in the c# app. For this i need to raise an event in c++/cli and consume it in C#. From MSDN I gather I need in my c++/cli class the following:

```
  delegate void Del(int);
  event Del^ E;
  void fire(int i) {
      E(i);
   }
```

[MSDN Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/58cwt3zh.aspx)

In MSDN the receiver of the event is in the same c++/cli project and it is shown how to raise the event. In my project, the c# app is to receive the event which should be raised in c++/cli after each file is processed. I've googled a lot too but have not been able to figure it out yet. So, my question is, how do I raise this event in c++/cli, and how do I connect my c# program to it? Some code that shows the way to do it would be greatly appreciated.
thanks!

Matt,
thanks for responding.
In C# I am trying

```
MW.Class1 oM = new MW.Class1();
oM.fire += ProgressBarChanged(int i);
```

It does not compile saying cannot assign because fire is a method group. I also have in my C# program, the handler

```
public void ProgressBarChanged(int i )
{

}
```

This does better though compiler says int is not expected and does not compile

```
oM.fire += new EventHandler(ProgressBarChanged(int i));
```

Comment: You would attach to the event in C# just like you would attach to any other event in C#.  Show us what you tried in C# that didn't work.

Comment: I edited and added more info to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, `fire` is a method, not an event. Call `+=` on the event, and leave off the `()` when you reference the event handler method.

```
oM.E += this.ProgressBarChanged;
```

As for firing the event, you're doing that correctly: Just call your event like a delegate or a method, passing the event arguments.